# CSS ">" selector to select particular div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>

<body>

<div> Mango </div>
<div> Apple </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to select second div which is "Apple" using CSS notation.

I am writing notation like this `:: html > body > div[2]`

Comment: Please show how your HTML looks like

Comment: please share your html and css code first

Comment: <html> <body> <div>Mango</div> <div> Apple </div> </body> </html>

Comment: You want to know the selector, or you want to know how to select an element in JavaScript using CSS notation?

Comment: i want to know how to select an element in javascript using CSS notation.

Comment: @user3534727 - Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/YPtnZ/

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 supported browsers use like below

```
 div:nth-child(2)
{
   background:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body div:nth-child(2)')
```

try here:
http://jsfiddle.net/D6w3g/

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript the only way, without using a library, to select with CSS notation is to use `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`; the difference between the two methods is that the first, `querySelector()` returns a single node, the first element, that matches the passed-in selector, whereas the second, `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, comprising of *all* the elements that match that selector.

To style elements, for example, using `querySelctor()`:

```
document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(2)').style.color = 'red';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/).

To style elements, again as an example, using `querySelectorAll()`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body > div:nth-child(2)');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/1/).

Or using `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body > div:nth-child(2)');

[].forEach.call(elements, function(a){
    a.style.color = 'red';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/2/).

Alternative selectors (if you want to style all `div` elements that *aren't* the `:first-child`:

```
/* selects all div elements that are immediate child of the body
   body element and are later-siblings of the div that is the
   ':first-child' */
body > div:first-child ~ div
```

[JS Fiddle demo using `querySelectorAll()` (with added `div` elements to illustrate)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/3/).
[JS Fiddle demo using `querySelector()` (with added `div` elements to illustrate)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/4/).

Or:

```
/* Selects all div elements that are the adjacent sibling of
   another div element, that is also an immediate child of
   the body element */
body > div + div
```

[JS Fiddle demo using `querySelectorAll()` (with added `div` elements to illustrate)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/6/).
[JS Fiddle demo using `querySelector()` (with added `div` elements to illustrate)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bW6MC/5/).

These approaches, using `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` do not, however, work under Internet Explorer less than version 9 (though IE 8 is 'incomplete,' so *may* offer sufficient compatibility).

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t13)</sup>.
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t14)</sup>.